# Wordpress Query Posts with Multiple Filters

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, filter

I'm using AJAX to filter posts by category, which is working fine.  But when I try to add another filter to filter by a custom field called album date my original category filter doesn't work.  Each filter on there own works but they don't work together.  Here is the stripped down code.

I'm still learning how this all works together so any help would be greatly appreciated!

**PHP CODE**

```
function my_filter_function(){

    // post date
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => $_POST['date']
    );

    // for taxonomies / categories
    if(isset($_POST['categoryfilter']))
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
            )
        );

    // album year
    if(isset($_POST['yearfilter']))
        $args = array(
            'meta_key'      => 'album_year',
            'meta_value'    => $_POST['yearfilter'],
        );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
            echo '<h1>' . $query->post->post_title . '</h1>';
            ...
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'No posts found';
    endif;
    
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'my_filter_function'); // wp_ajax_{ACTION HERE} 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'my_filter_function');
```

**FORM CODE**

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
    <?php
        // Category Filter
        if($terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'category', 'orderby' => 'name'))) : 
            echo '<select name="categoryfilter"><option value="">Select category...</option>';
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'; // ID of the category as the value of an option
            endforeach;
            echo '</select>';
        endif;
    ?>

    <?php 
        // Year Filter
        $posts = get_posts(array(
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'post_type'         => 'post',
            'meta_key'          => 'album_year',
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
            'order'             => 'DESC'
        ));

        if( $posts ): 
            echo '<select name="yearfilter"><option value="">Select Year...</option>';
                foreach($posts as $post): 
                    $album_year = get_field('album_year');
                    echo '<option value="' . $album_year . '">' . $album_year . '</option>';
                endforeach;
            echo '</select>';
            
            wp_reset_postdata();
        endif; 
    ?>
    
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="date" value="ASC" /> Date: Ascending
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="date" value="DESC" checked="checked" /> Date: Descending
    </label>
    
    <button>Apply filter</button>
    
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this code but it looks like you are overriding your `args` variable for `yearfilter`.

This

```php
// album year
if(isset($_POST['yearfilter'])) {
    $args = array(
        'meta_key'      => 'album_year',
        'meta_value'    => $_POST['yearfilter'],
    );
}
```

should be this

```php
// album year
if(isset($_POST['yearfilter'])) {
    $args['meta_key'] = 'album_year';
    $args['meta_value'] = $_POST['yearfilter'];
}
```

If they are working individually this should fix things.

Comment: hmmm, that is only working if a category AND a album date is selected.  If I select just an album date it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Actually this ended up working BUT I had to add a conditional to check for empty post vars like this if(isset($_POST['yearfilter']) && $_POST['yearfilter'] !="")